# Type mismatch on moving method from companion object to a class

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala, so the answer might be obvious.

When going through FP in Scala [FP in Scala](https://www.manning.com/books/functional-programming-in-scala) I noticed that the `unit` method is placed on the companion object, but not the class, so I tried moving it to the class.
It resulted in an error which I don't understand, can someone explain it to me?

When you uncomment the `unit` method on the class and comment it out on the companion object it results in this error:

[image: type mismatch]

Why is that?

```
import State._

case class State[S, A](run: S => (A, S)) {
  def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] =
    flatMap(a => unit(f(a)))

  def map2[B, C](sb: State[S, B])(f: (A, B) => C): State[S, C] =
    flatMap(a => sb.map(b => f(a, b)))

  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(s => {
    val (a, s1) = run(s)
    f(a).run(s1)
  })

  // This results in an error here:
  //     flatMap(a => unit(f(a))) ... Required A, found B
  // def unit(a: A): State[S, A] = State(s => (a, s)) // ERROR
}

object State {
  // Comment out when uncommenting above
  def unit[S, A](a: A): State[S, A] = State(s => (a, s))
}
```

Comment: Why are you moving `unit` from the object to the class? Class `State` encapsulates a function `S => (A, S)` so `map`, `map2`, `flatMap` make sense inside the class because they use `run` of the class `State`'s `this`. But `unit` doesn't (it's "static"). So moving `unit` from the object to the class seems strange decision. How are going to call it (if you don't have an instance of the class `State` yet)?

Comment: Thank you @DmytroMitin, this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error explains the problem, but here is the breakdown.

Start with `map`:

```
def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] =
  flatMap(a => unit(f(a)))
```

Since `f` returns an unknown type `B`, this is calling `unit` with a value of type `B`. But `unit` is defined to take `A`, which is a type parameter of the `case class`:

```
def unit(a: A): State[S, A] = State(s => (a, s))
```

Since `B` might not be `A`, the compiler complains.

---

The code inside the companion object is different:

```
object State {
  def unit[T, U](a: U): State[T, U] = State(s => (a, s))
}
```

I have re-named the type parameters to make it clear that they are now unrelated to the type parameters of the case class. And since the argument type of `unit` can be any type `U` it is OK to pass a value of type `B` to it.

---

To fix the definition of `unit` inside the `case class`, give it a type parameter:

```
case class State[S, A](run: S => (A, S)) {
   // ...

   def unit[T](a: T): State[S, T] = State(s => (a, s))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it's obvious!
As a novice, I confused the same letters inside the companion object and a class :)